# Can we generate random integers basing on Mean and SD in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have already generated data using np.random.normal but I am getting float values. I need to get Integers instead.
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: What probability distribution do you want? The normal distribution is a continuous distribution, so naturally the samples are returned as floats.

Comment: Basing on Mean and SD of my dataset feature

Comment: That doesn't tell us what distribution you want. It sounds like you don't actually know your requirements. While we might be able to provide a discrete distribution with a specified mean and standard deviation, it is highly likely that it'll turn out unusable due to some other requirement you didn't realize. Figure out what distribution you need, then come back and ask again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to get integers instead of float, you can try using int() to cast the value you are getting. Assuming you want a normal distribution of a thousand samples between -100 and 100, with a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1, you'd try this:

```
y = [int(x * 100) for x in np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)]
```

Here variable y holds the normal integer distribution you want.

Comment: This code does something completely different from either what you claim it does or what the question is asking for.